# pandas dataframe column based on row and multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe, I wish to add a new column called **open_next_year**.

This column will be selected by comparing two columns; **fiscalYear** + 1 and **ticker**.
Then using the value from column **open**.

Original dataframe:

```
   fiscalYear ticker     open  
         2017   FINL  17.4880  
         2017   AAPL  17.4880  
...
         2016   FINL  16.4880  
         2016   AAPL  16.4880  
         2015   FINL  15.4880  
         2015   AAPL  15.4880
```

Desired dataframe:

```
   fiscalYear ticker     open  open_next_year
         2017   FINL  17.4880  
         2017   AAPL  17.4880  
         2016   FINL  16.4880  17.4880 
         2016   AAPL  16.4880  17.4880
         2015   FINL  15.4880  16.4880 
         2015   AAPL  15.4880  16.4880
```

What is the pandas way to achieve this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need for each group shift all values by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
df['open_next_year'] = df.groupby('ticker')['open'].shift()
print (df)
   fiscalYear ticker    open  open_next_year
0        2017   FINL  17.488             NaN
1        2017   AAPL  17.488             NaN
2        2016   FINL  16.488          17.488
3        2016   AAPL  16.488          17.488
4        2015   FINL  15.488          16.488
5        2015   AAPL  15.488          16.488
```

Changed sample for unique `open` values:

```
print (df)
   fiscalYear ticker     open
0        2017   FINL  17.4881
1        2017   AAPL  17.4882
2        2016   FINL  16.4883
3        2016   AAPL  16.4884
4        2015   FINL  15.4885
5        2015   AAPL  15.4886

df['open_next_year'] = df.groupby('ticker')['open'].shift()
print (df)
   fiscalYear ticker     open  open_next_year
0        2017   FINL  17.4881             NaN
1        2017   AAPL  17.4882             NaN
2        2016   FINL  16.4883         17.4881
3        2016   AAPL  16.4884         17.4882
4        2015   FINL  15.4885         16.4883
5        2015   AAPL  15.4886         16.4884
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to take into account the 'fiscalYear'

Comment: OK, can you add more data to question?

Comment: @gibo - Can you add more data to sample? `fiscalYear` values are unique? Or not? There are multiple `ticker`s? Maybe 8 rows should be perfect with 2 groups if necessary.

Comment: Added. fiscalYear will be unique to the ticker, there are mulitple tickers

Comment: @gibo - thank you. But if there are unique years per groups, my solution working nice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach creating a map first.

```
m = dict(zip(tuple(zip(df.fiscalYear - 1, df.ticker)),df.open))
df['open_next_year'] = df[['fiscalYear','ticker']].apply(tuple, 1).map(m)
```

The map/dictionary looks like this and is obtained by *zipping* together year - 1, ticker and open value:

```
{(2014, 'AAPL'): 15.488,
 (2014, 'FINL'): 15.488,
 (2015, 'AAPL'): 16.488,
 (2015, 'FINL'): 16.488,
 (2016, 'AAPL'): 17.488,
 (2016, 'FINL'): 17.488}
```

**Full example:**

```
data = '''\
fiscalYear ticker    open
2017   FINL  17.488
2017   AAPL  17.488
2016   FINL  16.488
2016   AAPL  16.488
2015   FINL  15.488
2015   AAPL  15.488'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep='\s+')

m = dict(zip(tuple(zip(df.fiscalYear - 1, df.ticker)),df.open))
df['open_next_year'] = df[['fiscalYear','ticker']].apply(tuple, 1).map(m)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   fiscalYear ticker    open  open_next_year
0        2017   FINL  17.488             NaN
1        2017   AAPL  17.488             NaN
2        2016   FINL  16.488          17.488
3        2016   AAPL  16.488          17.488
4        2015   FINL  15.488          16.488
5        2015   AAPL  15.488          16.488
```